C# NHibernate SQLite dependencies in NetStandard 2 when using project reference
I have a C# project in which targets to NetStandard 2.0 using NHibernate and System.Data.SQLite.Core nuggets. I will call this project as SQliteProject.
I'm using NetStandard 2.0 because I want to reference this project from both NetFramework 4.8 and .Net8 projects.
After that I have a .Net8 library project which is referencing my SQliteProject. I will call this project as ProjectA.
I have added <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies> option in both SQLiteProject and ProjectA because I want SQLite and NHibernate dll to be copied to bin output dir.
I want to give ProjectA binaries to our client and he will use this project as reference or using maybe using reflection (my client is using Net8). I have been doing some testing with both options and I'm having problems with SQLite.Interop.dll.
When using project reference it seems that not all SQLite dlls are copied to output directory and project doesn't works. If I add Stub.System.Data.SQLite.Core.NetFramework nugget it seems to work but it's not ideal to add this nugget in this project since the SQLiteProject is the one which needs SQlite.
When using reflection to load ProjectA Assembly using Assembly.LoadFrom() also I'm getting the same error. The AssemblyLoader can't load SQLite.Interop.dll event it is present in the same folder as loaded dll.
I have done this type of references more times and I didn't have any problems doing things like so, but it seems that SQlite nuggets are causing me errors or maybe I'm not using the correct nugget packages.
